# Not so much a question as it is an added facet to an earlier question about sound propulsion

Tags: acoustics, frequency, dispersion

Ok so sound doesn't travel in space... But what about frequencies... And what about propulsion through Hz? Simply amplify one frequency at one speed then the next one a little faster but at a smaller Hz or what have you that way the second one bounces off the first one... Then do this in rapid succession ... Wouldn't this essentially project an object forward and as fast or slow as you basically wanted, depending on how many and where your amplifiers we're placed?

Comment: Please, find an informative title and add the link to the "earlier question about sound propulsion".

Answer (score 3):

Sound is a compression wave in a fluid medium, such like air. Air molecules wiggle back and forth and bump their neighbors in the process. That's how sound propagates. That's the same for all frequencies. Frequency is just a metric on how often per second the air molecules wiggle: the speed of sound propagation is a function of the medium itself and is independent of the frequency (mostly). In air, it's 344m/s.

It doesn't work in space since there is no medium. There no things that can wiggle and bump into neighbors. No matter how hard you push, there is nothing to push against.

Comment: I understand ... In space there is no matter to work with so to speak... But down on earth in the sky there's atmosphere/air hence something to bounce off.... So would sound propulsion work in our atmosphere ?